# Splitting string into unknown number of new dataframe columns

Tags: regex, r, string

I have a dataframe with a character column that contains email metadata in the form of multiple strings delimited by a newline character `\n`:

```
  person                                                                                                                                                 myString
1   John                                                                                                            To name5@email.com by sender6 on 01-12-2014\n
2   Jane To name@email.com,name4@email.com by sender1 on 01-22-2014\nTo name3@email.com by sender2 on 02-03-2014\nTo email5@domain.com by sender1 on 06-21-2014\n
3    Tim                                                                To name2@email.com by sender2 on 05-11-2014\nTo name@email.com by sender2 on 06-03-2015\n
```

I want to split the different substrings of myString into different columns so that it looks like this:

```
  person                                                     email1                                      email2                                        email3
1   John                To name5@email.com by sender6 on 01-12-2014                                        <NA>                                          <NA>
2   Jane To name@email.com,name4@email.com by sender1 on 01-22-2014 To name3@email.com by sender2 on 02-03-2014 To email5@domain.com by sender1 on 06-21-2014
3    Tim                To name2@email.com by sender2 on 05-11-2014  To name@email.com by sender2 on 06-03-2015                                          <NA>
```

My current approach uses `separate` from the tidyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
res1 <- df %>% 
    separate(col = myString, into = paste(rep("email", 3), 1:3), sep = "\\n", extra = "drop")
res1[res1 == ""] <- NA
```

But with this approach, I have to manually specify that there are three columns to extract.

I'm looking to improve this process with either or both of:

1. A way to automate that calculation of the maximum number of occurrences of the delimiting character (i.e., how many new variables are needed)
2. Other approaches to splitting into an unknown number of columns

And if there's a good solution that returns data in a long form, instead of wide, that would be great too.

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(person = c("John", "Jane", "Tim"), myString = c("To name5@email.com by sender6 on 01-12-2014\n", 
    "To name@email.com,name4@email.com by sender1 on 01-22-2014\nTo name3@email.com by sender2 on 02-03-2014\nTo email5@domain.com by sender1 on 06-21-2014\n", 
    "To name2@email.com by sender2 on 05-11-2014\nTo name@email.com by sender2 on 06-03-2015\n"
    )), .Names = c("person", "myString"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "myString", "\n")
#    person                                                 myString_1
# 1:   John                To name5@email.com by sender6 on 01-12-2014
# 2:   Jane To name@email.com,name4@email.com by sender1 on 01-22-2014
# 3:    Tim                To name2@email.com by sender2 on 05-11-2014
#                                     myString_2
# 1:                                          NA
# 2: To name3@email.com by sender2 on 02-03-2014
# 3:  To name@email.com by sender2 on 06-03-2015
#                                       myString_3
# 1:                                            NA
# 2: To email5@domain.com by sender1 on 06-21-2014
# 3:                                            NA
```

You can also try `stri_split_fixed` from the "stringi" package with the argument `simplify = TRUE` (though with your sample data, this adds an extra empty column at the end). The approach would be something like:

```
library(stringi)
data.frame(person = df$person, 
           stri_split_fixed(df$myString, "\n", 
                            simplify = TRUE))
```

Comment: This is great - the most straightforward function I've seen for this particular problem. Looks like there is other good stuff in this package too.  Thanks!

Comment: @SamFirke, Thanks. I hope you noticed that `cSplit` also has a "direction" argument that can be set to `"long"` if you want the long form.

Comment: just stopping by to thank you for that package. cSplit is a thing of beauty!

Answer (score 1):

Seems hacky, but here ya go...

Use strsplit to split the char vector. Get the max length, use that for your columns.

```
df <- data.frame(
  person = c("John", "Jane", "Tim"),
  myString = c("To name5@email.com by sender6 on 01-12-2014\n",
               "To name@email.com,name4@email.com by sender1 on 01-22-2014\nTo name3@email.com by sender2 on 02-03-2014\nTo email5@domain.com by sender1 on 06-21-2014\n",
               "To name2@email.com by sender2 on 05-11-2014\nTo name@email.com by sender2 on 06-03-2015\n"
  ), stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)

a <- strsplit(df$myString, "\n")
max_len <- max(sapply(a, length))
for(i in 1:max_len){
  df[,paste0("email", i)] <- sapply(a, "[", i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient route to a long form:

```
a <- strsplit(df$myString, "\n")
lens <- vapply(a, length, integer(1L)) # or lengths(a) in R 3.2
longdf <- df[rep(seq_along(a), lens),]
longdf$string <- unlist(a)
```

Note that `stack()` is often useful for these cases.

Can be simplified by using the IRanges Bioconductor package:

```
longdf <- df[togroup(a),]
longdf$string <- unlist(a)
```

Then, if really necessary, go to wide-form:

```
longdf$myString <- NULL
longdf$token <- sequence(lens)
widedf <- reshape(longdf, timevar="token", idvar="person", direction="wide")
```

Answer (score 1):

This might suffice:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df) # or setDT to convert in place

dt[, strsplit(myString, split = "\n"), by = person]
#   person                                                         V1
#1:   John                To name5@email.com by sender6 on 01-12-2014
#2:   Jane To name@email.com,name4@email.com by sender1 on 01-22-2014
#3:   Jane                To name3@email.com by sender2 on 02-03-2014
#4:   Jane              To email5@domain.com by sender1 on 06-21-2014
#5:    Tim                To name2@email.com by sender2 on 05-11-2014
#6:    Tim                 To name@email.com by sender2 on 06-03-2015
```

And then can trivially convert to wide format:

```
dcast(dt[, strsplit(myString, split = "\n"), by = person][, idx := 1:.N, by = person],
      person ~ idx, value.var = 'V1')
#   person                                                          1                                           2                                             3
#1:   Jane To name@email.com,name4@email.com by sender1 on 01-22-2014 To name3@email.com by sender2 on 02-03-2014 To email5@domain.com by sender1 on 06-21-2014
#2:   John                To name5@email.com by sender6 on 01-12-2014                                          NA                                            NA
#3:    Tim                To name2@email.com by sender2 on 05-11-2014  To name@email.com by sender2 on 06-03-2015                                            NA

# (load reshape2 and use dcast.data.table instead of dcast if not using 1.9.5+)
```

Comment: @SamFirke you don't need `reshape2` with latest version of `data.table` (edited comment at the end to make that clearer)

Comment: thanks for clarifying - I have the latest CRAN version of data.table, but I see that's 1.9.4, and 1.9.5 is the current dev't version on GitHub.  This works for me now.